# linking MVVM class to XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have the ViewModel Class below that i am using as a DataContext in XAML..

```
 public class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Model> Collection { get; set; }
        public ViewModel()
        {
            Collection = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
            GenerateDatas();
        }
        private void GenerateDatas()
        {
            this.Collection.Add(new Model(0, 1));
            this.Collection.Add(new Model(1, 2));
            this.Collection.Add(new Model(2, 3));
            this.Collection.Add(new Model(3, 4));
        }
    }
    public class Model
    {
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }

        public Model(double x, double y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }
```

i link it by creating a namespace of the application in the XAML as below:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication"
```

i then access the ViewModel as follows to serve as DataContext:

```
     <sparrow:SparrowChart.DataContext>
           <local:ViewModel/>
     </sparrow:SparrowChart.DataContext>
```

But i get an error that the name ViewModel doesn't exist in the local namespace..how do i go about fixing this?

The full XAML file:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="SparrowCharts.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clrnamespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:sparrow="clr-namespace:Sparrow.Chart;assembly=Sparrow.Chart.WP8.45"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication"

mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <sparrow:SparrowChart>
            <sparrow:SparrowChart.DataContext>
                <local:ViewModel/>
            </sparrow:SparrowChart.DataContext>
            <sparrow:SparrowChart.XAxis>
                <sparrow:LinearXAxis/>
            </sparrow:SparrowChart.XAxis>
            <sparrow:SparrowChart.YAxis>
                <sparrow:LinearYAxis/>
            </sparrow:SparrowChart.YAxis>
            <sparrow:LineSeries PointsSource="{Binding Collection}" XPath="X" YPath="Y"/>
        </sparrow:SparrowChart>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

the C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using MyApplication.Resources;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MyApplication
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }


    // Create a ViewModel
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Model> Collection { get; set; }
        public ViewModel()
        {
            Collection = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
            GenerateDatas();
        }
        private void GenerateDatas()
        {
            this.Collection.Add(new Model(0, 1));
            this.Collection.Add(new Model(1, 2));
            this.Collection.Add(new Model(2, 3));
            this.Collection.Add(new Model(3, 4));
        }
    }
    public class Model
    {
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }

        public Model(double x, double y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Your class might reside in a different namespace. If you are sure that your ViewModel Class resides in the namespace ViewModel and if your project runs, then you can Safely Ignore this error.

Comment: @Vishal the project cannot run with the error...the ViewModel Class resides in the application namespace that has been defined as the local namespace

Comment: Can you show me your full xaml file?

Comment: @EsotericScreenName did that :-)

Comment: Are you sure that your `ViewModel` class is actually in your `MyApplication` namespace? You didn't show that in your code example.

Comment: @Sheridan at the beginning of the c# file there's the namespace declaration whose scope i think covers the whole file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check on your curly braces,the `ViewModel` class should only be enclosed by the namespace curly brace and not the `MainPage` curly brace.Then you could create a new file for the `Model` class or place it way below the `MainPage` on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="SparrowCharts.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clrnamespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:sparrow="clr-namespace:Sparrow.Chart;assembly=Sparrow.Chart.WP8.45"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication"

mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <sparrow:SparrowChart>
            <sparrow:SparrowChart.XAxis>
                <sparrow:LinearXAxis/>
            </sparrow:SparrowChart.XAxis>
            <sparrow:SparrowChart.YAxis>
                <sparrow:LinearYAxis/>
            </sparrow:SparrowChart.YAxis>
            <sparrow:LineSeries PointsSource="{Binding DataContext.Collection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type phone:PhoneApplicationPage}}}" XPath="X" YPath="Y"/>
        </sparrow:SparrowChart>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could mention your change(s) to make your answer clearer @Vishal?

Comment: @Vishal,,thanks i tried it,still the same result..it is able to access the MainPage though..is there a method of accessing the class through the MainPage in such a way that <local:MainPage.ViewModel/>

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the view model resides in the correct namespace, try this declaration:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication;assembly="
```

Answer (score 0):

The ViewModel is nested within the Window. So its full name is `MyApplication.MainWindow.ViewModel`

Pull it out and put it in its own file and the correct namespace.

By the way: make sure the ViewModel class implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: gracias..saved a life